# The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri' on firebase function

Tags: firebase, flutter, package

I upgrade all the packages for Firebase.

After this upgrade, I have the below error message on all the reference of Firebase function.

How can we refer to the url with the new version of firebase.

> The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.dart(argument_type_not_

```
@override
  Future<bool> initiateRefund(Map initiateRefundMap) async {
    try {
      //refund
      switch (initiateRefundMap['paymentMethod']) {
        case 'CARD':
          Map<dynamic, dynamic> refundMap = {
            'transactionId': initiateRefundMap['transactionId'],
          };
          var refundRes = await http.post(
            'https://us-********-**********cloudfunctions.net/createStripeRefund', //TODO: Change this URL //it should look something like : https://us-********-**********.cloudfunctions.net/createStripeRefund
            body: refundMap,
          );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a Uri from the String and then pass it to the function. Try this code:

```dart
var uri = Uri.parse('https://us-********-**********cloudfunctions.net/createStripeRefund');
```

Comment: Eduardo, this is correct, I added after posting the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the url using Uri.parse
as Eduardo Pellenz said
`var uri = Uri.parse('url here');`
or if that doesn't work for you, as in my case I was using const instead of var as in above.
then try to parse the uri or variable/identifier instead of it's value/url.

```
var uri = "url here";
Uri.parse(uri);
```

or something similar, hope you get it, still have doubts or issues feel free to reply this answer